# Inner join with 2 tables or foreign key in sql database?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

I want to get the product name from the `Products` table to the `CustomerProducts` table.

`Products` table:

[image: Products]

`customerproducts` table:

[image: customerproducts]

UPDATE:

```
public void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name From Products p InnerJoin CustomerProducts cp ON(p.ProductID = cp.ProductID)", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select ProductName From Products p InnerJoin CustomerProducts cp ON(p.ProductID = cp.ProductID", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: The links do not work.

Comment: Inner join and Foreign key are different tools for different purposes. Your question is like asking Motorcycle or kitchen knife. Please do some research.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: expected result sir@jarlh is `CustomerID, ProductID, and ProductName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it as a select :

```
SELECT cp.customerID,cp.productID,p.name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN customerProducts cp
 ON(p.productID = cp.productID)
```

If you want to add a column to the second table, first add the column, and then update:

```
UPDATE customerProducts cp
SET cp.name = (SELECT p.name FROM products p
               WHERE p.productID = cp.productID)
```

Comment: What's wrong with my query? I don't see any new question after the update.

Comment: gives me an error sir `Incorrect syntax near 'InnerJoin'.`

Comment: You are missing a space between `INNER` and `JOIN`

Comment: gives me an error. `incorrect syntax near ProductID` what i want sir is to have, `CustomerID,ProductID,ProductName`

Comment: This is what my first query returns! just copy it as it is.

Comment: Because you only select `NAME` , change it to my query!@!